# Problema al iniciar Ubuntu en OracleVM Virtual Box

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Al cargar un archivo ova en la máquina virtual e intentar abrirlo, me aparece este mensaje
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No creo que sea un problema de permisos de Windows, ya que ya activé las características para "Plataforma de máquina virtual" y "Plataforma del hipervisor de Windows"; también me aseguré de activar la opción de virtualización en mi procesador (AMD); y tengo la última versión de Windows instalada, algo que leí que también suele dar problemas.

¿Alguna idea?

Dejo por aquí las características de mi ordenador, por si pudieran ser de ayuda:
Procesador AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core
Windows 10 Pro versión 22H2

Un saludo y gracias de antemano

Comment: si no vas a usar hyper-v de microsoft desactivalo ( deja el soporte en el bios activado ) no debería dar problemas con las últimas versiones de vbox pero... es lento

Comment: Estimado: consulta en el BIOS de la maquina o computadora habilitaste el tema de que el CPU puede aceptar virtualizar? Te comparto este video de youtube para que lo valides: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHW3-m1sO1s